# Is there possible chache query or save it in memory in MySql? Mayby Should I use something other?

Tags: mysql, innodb, memory, cache, memcached

I have complicated query (some joins and ordering), that I want to execute very often. Results of query can change very rarely.

Query gets words form given language and category sorted by frequency, so it have two parameters - language and category.

I heart about materialized views, or databases in memory, bu I do not have experience enough to consider cons and props in reasonable way.

I want to have possibility execute this query for these parameters, and next not execute it until I decide manually, that it must be refreshed. In practice, all application based on executing this query many times, so I do not know if can I create one view in memory, when database use innodb.

I can change mysql on something else, and innodb too if is it recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try the Query cache first.  Add these to my.cnf, then restart mysql:

```
query_cache_type = ON
query_cache_size = 50M
```

If that does not work adequately, we can discuss alternatives.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful an I did one step next. But now I have problem with caching query with numeration added after ordering. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157360/how-to-cache-select-with-variables-mysql so we can discuss alternatives :)