# How to cache select with variables? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, order-by, cache, sorting, memcached

### Context:

I have complicated very often executed query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ordered_words AS SELECT word.id
  FROM category JOIN frequency ON category.id = frequency.category_id
    JOIN word ON frequency.word_id = word.id
    JOIN language ON word.language_id = language.id
  WHERE
    category.name='Subtitles' AND iso_639_1='en'
  ORDER BY frequency.value DESC;
```

I enabled cache `query_cache_type=1` and I obtain great performance improvement.

**First time (4.5 s)**

```
sql> SELECT * FROM ordered_words
500 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 4s 585ms (execution: 4s 576ms, fetching: 9ms)
```

**Second time (5 ms)**

```
sql> SELECT * FROM ordered_words
500 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 11ms (execution: 5ms, fetching: 6ms)
```

It is ok.

---

### Problem

But now I want to add to this result one column with identifiers 1,2,3... because I would like to be able to get selected row from result of this query. I created the following query:

```
SELECT @ROW := @ROW + 1 AS ROW
 FROM ordered_words t
 join (SELECT @ROW := 0) t2;
```

But this query is not cached. Any time execution gets about 4.8 sec. I want to save to cache result of this query.

#### Alternative solutions:

Because of my experience in databases is small. I do not know if my approach is optimal so I describe wider context. In my application inserts are very rarely used.

My real target is execute very often query that get one random element from `ordered_words` with dynamically assigned distribution of probability. I do not want to create new table for this, because category and language are free parameters. I will use function rather. But I do not want execute all query any time.

Logic of randomization will be executed out of MySQL. MySQL will obtain only number of word in temporal order saved in result of `ordered_words`. I am planning treat column `row` as temporary identifier that allow select `word_id` without calculating all joins and ordering from first mentioned query.

Maybe is there something like temporary table created in memory, or should I use other database system?

[image: schema]

---

## Update

As @Rick-James suggest. Timing was wrong. Cache was created by my IDE - DataGrip not by MySQL. Finally I decided to save result of my complicated query to table in memory by command:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words_memory_subtitles_en (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, word_id INTEGER)
  ENGINE=MEMORY
  AS
  SELECT word.id as word_id
    FROM category JOIN frequency ON category.id = frequency.category_id
      JOIN word ON frequency.word_id = word.id
      JOIN language ON word.language_id = language.id
    WHERE
      category.name='Subtitles' AND iso_639_1='en'
    ORDER BY frequency.value DESC;
```

I will mange creating and removing tables like this in PHP.

I decided to remove `id` from `frequency` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficient fetch of a random row, [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) is a blog on such.

Do you really select *all* columns of *all* rows, as indicated in the timings you mention?

Keep in mind that *all* entires for a given table in the "Query cache" are deleted whenever *any* write operation happens on that table.  (This makes the QC rarely of any use in busy production servers.)

A common mistake in many-to-many table is to have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id.  Check out that and other [*many:many tips here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

`VIEWs` are a convenience, not a way to get efficiency.  Pretend you don't have the `VIEW` and write the *real* query you need.  If it is 'fast enough', then I have given you the answer.  If not, let's see it and look for ways to optimize it.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each relevant table.